# Average of VMO-function continuous

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, continuity, harmonic-analysis

Does anyone know why for given $f\in \operatorname{VMO}(S^1)$, where VMO is the room of Vanishing Mean Oscillation as in [D.Sarason, Functions of VMO](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1975-207-00/S0002-9947-1975-0377518-3/S0002-9947-1975-0377518-3.pdf), the map
$$I_{\varepsilon}f(x) := \frac 1 {\operatorname{vol}(B_{\varepsilon}(x))} \int\limits_{B_{\varepsilon}(x)} f(y) \, dy $$
is continuous in $x$ for all $\varepsilon$?

Thanks!

Comment: ok, I thought for a moment "VMO" might mean "vanishing mean oscillation", but I don't see that that applies to a circle, which is, after all, compact. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy BMO and VMO can be defined on [the circle too](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1975-207-00/S0002-9947-1975-0377518-3/S0002-9947-1975-0377518-3.pdf).

Comment: Jep "VMO" is "vanishing mean oscillation". Does no one have a clou? In sources like Brezis-Nirenberger its not explained...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's continuous because $\operatorname{VMO}\subset\operatorname{BMO}\subset\operatorname{L^1}$ and in $L^1$ 
$$x\mapsto \int\limits_{B_{\varepsilon}(x)}f(y)dy$$
is continuous.